# How I can use a function which returns a table in a select statement with an inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to use a function which returns a table, in a inner join sentence passing a parameter.  When executed, the sentence like this is not working.

```
SELECT T0.Code,T0.Data1,T0,Data2 FROM  [dbo].[FNGet_Data] (T1.Code,'2010-01','USD') T0 
INNER JOIN 
Codes T1 ON T1.Code=T0.Code
```

When executed the sentence using a constant parameter works ok

```
SELECT T0.Code,T0.Data1,T0,Data2 FROM  [dbo].[FNGet_Data] ('5200','2010-01','USD') T0 
INNER JOIN 
Codes T1 ON T1.Code=T0.Code
```

Is it possible to call the function `FNGet_Data` using as parameter the value of another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Using APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx)